# Returning to camera screen after onResume() leads to PlatformException

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a camera screen that uses [mlkit-barcode](https://pub.dev/packages/google_mlkit_barcode_scanning) library for qr scanning & the flutter camera package for image capturing and live preview functionality. I want to make sure that if a user puts the app in the background (i.e., by going back to the home screen) and then returning, that everything will keep working as intended. This seems to work fine with the `didChangeLifecycleState` callback in its current state, but leads to a crash after a specific flow is executed. Here is the flow:

1. Take a picture in order to navigate to the second screen
2. Go back to the camera screen
3. Put the app in the background & come back to it
4. The live preview, qr scanning & image capturing functionalities stop working

The exception I'm seeing in the logs is:

```
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(error, Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Surface android.media.ImageReader.getSurface()' on a null object reference, null, java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Surface android.media.ImageReader.getSurface()' on a null object reference
```

From what I have found on Flutter's GitHub page, this issue is still occurring for many users, but the issues keep getting closed. Does anybody have any workarounds if my code isn't the issue? If it is, please point me in the right direction.

Here's a minimum, reproducible example (main.dart):

```
Future<void> main() async {
  // Ensure that plugin services are initialized so that `availableCameras()`
  // can be called before `runApp()`
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark(),
      initialRoute: '/camera',
      routes: {
        // When navigating to the "/" route, build the FirstScreen widget.
        '/camera': (context) => const TakePictureScreen(),
      },
    ),
  );
}

// A screen that allows users to take a picture using a given camera.
class TakePictureScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const TakePictureScreen({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  TakePictureScreenState createState() => TakePictureScreenState();
}

class TakePictureScreenState extends State<TakePictureScreen>
    with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  CameraController? _controller;
  final BarcodeScanner _barcodeScanner = BarcodeScanner();
  bool _canProcess = true;
  bool _isBusy = false;
  //Future<void>? _initializeControllerFuture;
  String codeValue = 'default';
  CameraDescription? _camera;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
    setUp();
  }

  Future<void> setUp() async {
    _canProcess = true;
    // Obtain a list of the available cameras on the device.
    final cameras = await availableCameras();

    // Get a specific camera from the list of available cameras.
    _camera = cameras.first;
    // To display the current output from the Camera,
    // create a CameraController.
    _controller = CameraController(
        // Get a specific camera from the list of available cameras.
        _camera!,
        // Define the resolution to use.
        ResolutionPreset.high,
        enableAudio: false);

    // await startCameraProcessing();
    _controller?.initialize().then((_) {
      if (!mounted) {
        return;
      }
      debugPrint('started stream');
      _controller?.startImageStream(_processCameraImage);
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    log(state.name);
    // final CameraController? cameraController = _controller;
    // // App state changed before we got the chance to initialize.
    // if (cameraController == null || !cameraController.value.isInitialized) {
    //   return;
    // }

    if (state == AppLifecycleState.inactive) {
      log('inactive being called');
      cleanup();
    } else if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
      log('on resume called');
      // _controller != null
      //     ? _initializeControllerFuture = _controller!.initialize()
      //     : null;
      setUp();
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    cleanup();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Future cleanup() async {
    _canProcess = false;
    _isBusy = false;
    _barcodeScanner.close();
    if (_controller != null && _controller!.value.isInitialized) {
      try {
        await _controller?.stopImageStream();
      } catch (e) {
        print(e);
      }
    }
    await _controller?.dispose();
    _controller = null;
  }

  Future _processCameraImage(CameraImage image) async {
    debugPrint('inside _pr');
    final WriteBuffer allBytes = WriteBuffer();
    for (final Plane plane in image.planes) {
      allBytes.putUint8List(plane.bytes);
    }
    final bytes = allBytes.done().buffer.asUint8List();

    final Size imageSize =
        Size(image.width.toDouble(), image.height.toDouble());

    final imageRotation =
        InputImageRotationValue.fromRawValue(_camera!.sensorOrientation);
    debugPrint('image rotation = ' + imageRotation.toString());
    if (imageRotation == null) return;

    final inputImageFormat =
        InputImageFormatValue.fromRawValue(image.format.raw);
    debugPrint('image format = ' + inputImageFormat.toString());
    if (inputImageFormat == null) return;

    final planeData = image.planes.map(
      (Plane plane) {
        return InputImagePlaneMetadata(
          bytesPerRow: plane.bytesPerRow,
          height: plane.height,
          width: plane.width,
        );
      },
    ).toList();

    final inputImageData = InputImageData(
      size: imageSize,
      imageRotation: imageRotation,
      inputImageFormat: inputImageFormat,
      planeData: planeData,
    );

    final inputImage =
        InputImage.fromBytes(bytes: bytes, inputImageData: inputImageData);

    debugPrint('before process');
    processImage(inputImage);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Take a picture')),
      // You must wait until the controller is initialized before displaying the
      // camera preview. Use a FutureBuilder to display a loading spinner until the
      // controller has finished initializing.
      body: _controller?.value.isInitialized == true
          ? Stack(
              children: [
                CameraPreview(_controller!),
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Text(
                    codeValue,
                    style: const TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.red,
                      fontSize: 25,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            )
          : const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        // Provide an onPressed callback.
        onPressed: () async {
          // Take the Picture in a try / catch block. If anything goes wrong,
          // catch the error.
          try {
            // Ensure that the camera is initialized.
            if (!_controller!.value.isInitialized) {
              return;
            }

            // Attempt to take a picture and get the file `image`
            // where it was saved.

            // STREAM MUST BE STOPPED before taking a picture. Otherwise we get crash.
            await _controller!.stopImageStream();
            final image = await _controller!.takePicture();

            if (!mounted) return;

            // If the picture was taken, display it on a new screen.
            await Navigator.of(context).push(
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => DisplayPictureScreen(
                  // Pass the automatically generated path to
                  // the DisplayPictureScreen widget.
                  imagePath: image.path,
                ),
              ),
            );
          } catch (e) {
            // If an error occurs, log the error to the console.
            print(e);
          }
        },
        child: const Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
      ),
    );
  }

  void processImage(InputImage inputImage) async {
    debugPrint('can process = ' +
        _canProcess.toString() +
        ' and isbusy = ' +
        _isBusy.toString());
    if (!_canProcess) return;
    if (_isBusy) return;
    _isBusy = true;
    debugPrint('called process');
    setState(() {
      codeValue = 'test';
    });
    final barcodes = await _barcodeScanner.processImage(inputImage);
    for (final barcode in barcodes) {
      setState(() {
        debugPrint('called in barcode loop');
        codeValue += 'Barcode: ${barcode.rawValue}\n\n';
      });
    }
    _isBusy = false;
    if (mounted) {
      setState(() {});
    }
  }
}

// A widget that displays the picture taken by the user.
class DisplayPictureScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final String imagePath;

  const DisplayPictureScreen({super.key, required this.imagePath});

  @override
  State<DisplayPictureScreen> createState() => _DisplayPictureScreenState();
}

class _DisplayPictureScreenState extends State<DisplayPictureScreen> {
  String? codeValue;
  Future<void> checkImageForCode() async {
    XFile xFile = XFile(widget.imagePath);
    CodeResult? resultFromXFile = await readBarcodeImagePath(xFile);
    print('Image code is ${resultFromXFile?.textString}');
    codeValue = resultFromXFile?.textString;
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    checkImageForCode();
  }

  Future<bool> _onPopAsync() async {
    Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement<void, void>(
      MaterialPageRoute<void>(
        builder: (BuildContext context) => const TakePictureScreen(),
      ),
    );
    return true;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: _onPopAsync,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Display the Picture')),
        // The image is stored as a file on the device. Use the `Image.file`
        // constructor with the given path to display the image.
        body: Stack(
          children: [
            Image.file(File(widget.imagePath)),
            if (codeValue != null)
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                child: Text(
                  '$codeValue',
                  style: const TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.red,
                    fontSize: 25,
                  ),
                ),
              )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```